# Ok to pass IDs in query string?

Tags: asp.net, query-string

Is it okay to pass IDs in the query string? For example:

> example.com/viewperson.aspx?personid=22d62e18-2383-42ca-ba6d-a535355b98bb

Does this change (less risk) for an intranet site?

If a public site, assume anyone can access (shoulder serving, browser logging, etc).. even though we’re under SSL I still assume “out there”. Obviously, security will be applied to disallow an unauthenticated user from viewing page.  But still a risk?

An added benefit of using query string is bookmarking a few (e.g. persons in this case) you want to call back up without having to go through the front door and look back up.
Would never pass anything meaningful, but maybe an ID is meaningful enough to not pass?

An alternative would be a cookie or session variable, of course.

Comment: [Relevant](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Insecure_Direct_Object_References_(OTG-AUTHZ-004)#Summary)

Comment: Query string id's are bad, mkay?

Comment: Use query string saves a user's time to search for that user or sharing, personally, I prefer using query string than session

Comment: @User2012384, actually it is. The question is too broad and/or opinon based. There is no right or wrong answer since it could depend on a specific set of requirements of the OP of which we have no knowledge.

Comment: Optimistic answer: It's ok to use with encryption since this is an intranet site. Pessimistic answer: No. In short: Opinion based.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming these are resources you want protected its not a risk provided that requests for resources by id are both authenticated and authorised. Meaning you should verify that the request comes from a logged in user and that the user has access to that resource.

So if I belong to company 5 i shouldn't be able to open /companies/4.

Otherwise no issues and there is no alternative approach I am aware of. (by which I mean you must provide an identifier somehow)

Comment: "No alternative approach" did you read the question? It actually mentions two of them.

Comment: @mason i mean there is no alternative to providing an identifier. You cannot request a resource if you do not identify it. While the op is asking about querystring specifically his concern seems to be security risks in exposing the id/allowing a resource to be requested by id. The point I am making is theres no way to *not* do that.

Comment: Sure there is. You just don't expose it to the client. As long as you can tie each client to an individual session, you can store that sort of information server side. It doesn't make for a good user experience, but it's definitely doable.